# Error al ejecutar procedure parametros unknown en PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Lo que pasa es que he creado un procedure y cuando llamo a este con un call me dice lo siguiente:

> ERROR:  no existe el procedimiento «insertar_datos_apunte(unknown,
>   unknown, date, numeric, integer)» LINE 1: call
>   insertar_datos_apunte('el gato con botas','10TC',date('...
>
> Ningún procedimiento coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos.
>   Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.

el código de procedure es el siguiente:

```
create or replace procedure insertar_datos_apunte(tit character varying,codas  character varying,fechaed date,cos numeric(5,2),validez_e smallint) 
as $$
    begin
    insert into apunte(titulo, cod_as, fecha_ed, costo, validez) values(tit,codas,fechaed,cos,validez_e);
    end
$$ language plpgsql
```

y lo llamo así:

```
call insertar_datos_apunte('el gato con botas','10TC',date('12/12/2012'),100.4,0);
```

Ya he buscado en google y no me aparecen muchos resultados. Gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que hacer casts para que fuera compatible:

```
call insertarDatosApunte('el gato','10TC',date('2012-01-12'),cast( 100.20 as numeric(5,2)), cast( 0 as smallint));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné definiendo parámetros en el comando sql de Postgres. Allí le debes especificar el tipo de datos en el mismo orden de tu función a procedimiento.

```sql
psqlstring = "insertar_datos_apunte(@tit, @codas, @fechaed,@cos,validez_e)  
CmdSql = new NpgsqlCommand(psqlstring, cnndb);
CmdSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//Pasamos los parámetros
CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tit",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text, 'el gato con botas');
CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codas",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text, '10TC');
....

try
{ 
  CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex){
  throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
finally
{ }
```